# Can I be compensated for a rescheduled Air India flight?

Tags: india, airlines, compensation

My flight FRA-DEL AI0120 was cancelled after boarding and rescheduled for the next day. I was given a transit hotel to stay in, but I lost a day. Do I get compensation for this delay?

Comment: Did you contact Air India ?

Comment: Being managed by Government there's a less likely chance that you'll be facilitated with compensation, but there's absolutely NO harm is asking Air India about it..!

Answer (score 4):

Under [EU Regulation 261/2004](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=URISERV:l24173), passengers are entitled to compensation for cancelled or heavily delayed flights when the delay is not caused by an extraordinary circumstance, such as bad weather or crew strikes. The flight must depart from an EU airport, operated by any airline, or it must arrive into an EU airport and be operated by an EU airline.

To claim compensation for a delay, you should write to [Air India](http://www.airindia.in/customer-support.htm), and include all relevant details, such as:

- passenger(s) number
- booking or reservation number
- flight number
- date
- reason for delay (as told to you)
- departure airport
- arrival airport
- scheduled departure time
- number of hours it arrived late
- time and date of arrival

You should acknowledge what you were provided (hotel accommodation, transport between airport and hotel, meal costs) and, if any of those costs were not covered, you should include receipts for those expenses you incurred.